# Problema com SQLite no método onPostExecute do AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, asynctask

Estou com um problema para executar uma função do SQLite no método onPostExecute do AsyncTask. Quando implemento a mesma função na Activity ele executa normalmente, mas no onPostExecute não entra nem no breakpoint que coloquei na função.

A função que realiza o update do usuário é a seguinte:

```
public class UpdateDatabaseOff{
    ...
    public static void updateUser(Context context, JSONObject object){
        try{
            User user;
            user = new User(object);
            Queries.setDataToDatabase(context, User.tableName, user);
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A classe Queries e a função setDataToDatabase estão abaixo:

```
public static Integer setDataToDatabase(Context context, String tableName, GenericsTable genericsTable){
    long id = -1;

    getDatabase(context).get().beginTransaction();
    try {
        if (genericsTable.getSingleCode() != null) {
            int rowsUpdate = getDatabase(context).get().update(tableName, genericsTable.getContentValues(), genericsTable.getSingleCode(), null);
            if (rowsUpdate == 0) {
                id = getBanco(context).get().insert(tableName, null, genericsTable.getContentValues());
            }else{
                StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
                query.append(" SELECT id FROM " + tableName);
                query.append(" WHERE " + genericsTable.getSingleCode() );

                final Cursor cursor = Queries.getSelect(context, query);
                id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            }
        }else{
            id = getBanco(context).get().insert(tableName, null, genericsTable.getContentValues());
        }
        getBanco(context).get().setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        getBanco(context).get().endTransaction();
    }

    return new Integer(String.valueOf(id));
}
```

Então, finalmente, faço a chamada da função updateUser no onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JsonReturn jsonReturn){
    ...
    UpdateDatabaseOff.updateUser(context, jsonenvio); //Não funciona
}
```

Não sei o que pode ser. Tentei colocar a função numa Thread e nada.
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda :)

Comment: marcou o método onPostExecute com @override?

Comment: Marquei @Geferson, obrigado pela resposta. Eu resolvi o problema, vou responder minha pergunta pra fechar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, não estava passando valor algum para o `user` no momento de receber esse valor no doInBackground. Para entendimento:

Na chamada da AsyncTask, eu agora setei o valor do user

```
JsonParameter jsonParameter = new JsonParameter();
jsonParameter.setUser(user);
...
ConnectTask connectTask = new ConnectTask(context);
connectTask.execute(jsonParameter);
```

Então na AsyncTask agora tem o valor do user:

```
protected JsonReturn doInBackground(JsonParameter... params){
    ...
    user = params[0].getUser();
}
```